# Read mails stored in my android gmail app

Tags: android, gmail, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to read the emails sorted in my android **gmail app** by using a `content resolver` or any other way?
I know that this is a dirty way but the app will not be published.

**To gain access to gmail via javamail would not be an option.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to access the Gmail apps email, unless you create a email application and user loges in the same from that app with same gmail credentials.

Comment: The reason for that is that i am looking for an offline search of my mails i already have in cache. Google doesnt implement it yet and this is a big feature for me. Any ideas how to do an offline search ?

Comment: the default gmail does not provide it, But there are some app that allow you to have offline search.  http://www.tested.com/tech/android/3110-the-best-alternative-android-apps-to-manage-all-your-email/